# Average values in Excel that fulfil a condition referring to many columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, average

I’m actually used to Excel but not able to solve the following problem:

My column AA consists of 300 records with values of which I wanna calculate the average but I dont want to calcualte the average of each value, I rather want to average all values that fulfil certain conditions. The result should be shown in one cell, I DON’T WANNA USE A HELP COLUMN.

I’ve already tried AVERAGEIFS :

```
AVERAGEIFS($AA:$AA,$BW:$BW,<>0,….
```

but I’m not able to implement my complication condition:

```
(ROUND($AG:$AG+($AG:$AG*(1-IFERROR(AI:AI/$AG:$AG,0))),0)) = (ROUND($AH:$AH+($AH:$AH*(1-IFERROR(BC:BC/$AH:$AH,0))),0))
```

So I only wanna average the values of column AA that meet the condition BW<>0 and the complicated condition above in the same row.

Is anybody able to help?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Complicated condition in words (only first part before the equal sign):

I substract the ratio AI/AG from 1 to get the negative or positive percetage change. For example:
If e.g. AI/AG=1.2 is substracted from 1, I get -0.2
If e.g. AI/AG=0.8 is subtracted from 1, I get 0.2

This result (e.g. 0.2) needs to be multiplied by AG to finally add up the product with AG, 
if you assume AG=1.3 the calculation would be:
AG*0.2=0,26 => AG + 0.26 = 1.56

This result needs to be rounded which would deliver 2.

The whole description above can be applied analogously to the second part (behind the euqal sign).

The actual condition requires the result of part one equal to part two, to follow the example, the condition would be fulfiled if 2=2.

Comment: You can prolly use `SUMPRODUCT`. What is your complication condition in words?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: I have edited my original post (including my complicated condition in words). Thank you!

Comment: I guess using sumproduct would not work in this case, I just don't know how to implement this condition into AVERAGEIFS since this single (complicated) condition/criteria depends on various criteria ranges